# Ошибка CS0120 Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Application.Exit" требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: c#, wpf

Вот такая проблема хочу закрыть приложение через Application.Exit но происходит ошибка.
Тип приложения: Приложение  WPF(.NET Framework), помогите пожалуйста
Код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
//using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace NPGF_Launcher
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"bin_Win32\xrEngine.exe"; //путь
            bool fileExist = File.Exists(path);

            if (fileExist)
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
            else
                MessageBox.Show($"Файл по пути: {path}. Проверьте наличие файла или переустановите программу!", "Не найден файл!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

                     Application.Exit() ; //Тут ошибка    
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Application.Exit()` замените на `Close()`, а так `Application.Current.Exit()` наверное надо, но я бы не советовал.

Comment: _Application.Exit() замените на Close()_ Оно разве не закрывает просто окно?

Comment: А вам что надо? При закрытии последнего окна закрывается все приложение, это является основным и самым правильным способом выхода.

Comment: _А вам что надо? При закрытии последнего окна закрывается все приложение, это является основным и самым правильным способом выхода._ Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Версия дотнета какая? Здесь есть еще один нюанс. `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(path) { UseShellExecute = true });` - вот так правильно для любой версии дотнета будет.

Comment: _{ UseShellExecute = true }_ а это за что отвечает?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute